# What is the difference between NをNとする and NをNとして/に?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am very confused about とする vs. として/に. I am working on the Try book for N2 and in one of the practices it's asking to pick between とする, として, and に in example sentences.

> 企業は利益を上げることを目的(として/とする),日々、経済活動を行っている。

Answer (score 5):

Simply, ～とする is adjectival (modifies a *noun* as a relative clause), and ～として is adverbial (modifies a *verb* as a te-form).

The next *noun* after the modifier in question is 日々. It's a noun that also works as an adverb, just like 明日, 去年, 今月, etc. If you say 利益を上げることを目的と**する**, it looks like it modifies 日々, and the whole sentence would look like "Companies conduct economic activities in the profit-pursuing days", which makes little sense because there is no such a thing as "non-profit-pursuing days" of a company. Instead, this modifier must modify the next *verb*, (経済活動を)行う.

> 企業は利益を上げることを目的として日々経済活動を行っている。
>   Companies conduct economic activities every day with the purpose of making a profit.

In the English translation, you can see "with the purpose of making a profit" is modifying not "every day" but "conduct economic activities".

AをBに is also adverbial. It's perfectly fine to say 企業は利益を上げることを目的に日々経済活動を行っている, too.

---

By the way, What if there is no 日々?

> 1. 企業は利益を上げることを目的として経済活動を行っている。
> 2. 企業は利益を上げることを目的とする経済活動を行っている。

Both are grammatical, but still, the former is more natural. In Sentence 1, 経済活動を行っている is adverbially modified by 利益を上げることを目的として ("Why companies do economic activities? Because they want to make a profit!"). This makes sense. In Sentence 2, 経済活動 is adjectivally modified by 利益を上げることを目的とする ("What kind of economic activity? The one that can make a profit!"). This sounds odd because it sounds as if there were such a thing as "non-profit-pursuing economic activity".