# What does 白と茶色を基調とする mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, set-phrases

> **白と茶色を基調とした**真新しい洋風の外壁。

I saw that ～を～とする means "as" and that 基調 means "to be the main color in something like a picture" ([2nd definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%9F%BA%E8%AA%BF/#jn-52768)), but I can't link everything in this sentence.

"Brown as white"? (Or is it "white as brown" because the wall was brown actually. I'll upload a picture). Should I consider it as "instead" instead of "as"? For example, "white instead of brown"...? Considering that there is both white and brown in the image, it looks the game is talking about both the colors, but I don't know which would be the main one.

[image]

Comment: "... that uses white and light brown as base colors" https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74139  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54632  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33722  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18593  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73082  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83751

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three words/phrases are modifying 外壁:

- 〖白**と**茶色〗を〖基調〗とした
  which uses 〖white **and** brown〗 as 〖base colors〗
- 真新しい
  new
- 洋風の
  western-style

Note that 白 and 茶色 are joined with と ("and"). Here 白と茶色 is a set, and comes before the "as".